# Compare incoming object with record in the database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to compare two objects in rails, the first is from a new record and the other is a record in the database but I have not achieved it, what I have been doing is the following:

```
def update
  new_biological_target = params[:biological_target]
  old_biological_target = BiologicalTarget.find(params[:biological_target][:id])

  if new_biological_target == old_biological_target
    message="Equals"
  else
    message="different"
  end
end
```

What I want to compare is that if the user made any changes to the registry

Comment: Well, that's not going to work because you're comparing a `Hash` to an instance of `BiologicalTarget`. Also, what constitutes 'Equals`?

Comment: That the user has not made any changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned here, you are comparing two different types. I assume you are comparing a Hash and a BiologicalTarget.

One solution is to loop through new_biological_target, and compare the values of new_biological_target to the values in the old_biological_target record.

```
# can initially set message to equal
message = 'equal'

new_biological_target.each do |key, value|
  # make sure the record even has the attribute, then if it does, check to see if the values are the same 
  if old_biological_target.has_attribute?(key) && old_biological_target.attributes[key] == value
    # move to next iteration of loop because the attribute was the same as value
    next
  # the params you are passing either have additional keys that aren't contained in the record, so handle however you want, in this case I am saying the object is different, or the value was different for the key
  else
    message = 'different'
    break
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ActiveModel::Dirty - changed?](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed-3F)

```
biological_target = BiologicalTarget.find(params[:biological_target][:id])

message = biological_target.assign_attributes(params[:biological_target]).changed? ? "Different" : "Equals"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing to different types, `params[:biological_target]` is, most likely, an instance of `Hash` and `BiologicalTarget.find` is an instance of `BiologicalTarget` therefore `==` will always be `false`.

You could try converting your model to a Hash of attributes, as such:

```
new_biological_target = params[:biological_target]
old_biological_target = BiologicalTarget.find(params[:biological_target][:id]).attributes
new_biological_target == old_biological_target # => true/false
```

But this is unlikely to work because the params being submitted from the form will not have `created_at`, `updated_at` or `id` attributes, for starters.

You would be better off trying to create a new model using the params and use model validations and/or database constraints to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: What I want to compare is that if the user made any changes to the registry

Comment: what is a registry?

Comment: A record in the database

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, [assign_attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes). So, you could do something like:

```
  biological_target = BiologicalTarget.find(params[:biological_target][:id])
  biological_target.assign_attributes biological_target_params
  biological_target.changed?
    message = "Changed"
  else 
    message = "Unchanged"
  end
```

You'll want to make sure to process those parameters so you don't get a mass assignment error.